# Setting up Windows Server 2003 IP settings as Guest OS (VM)

Tags: windows-server-2003, virtualbox, nat

I'm trying to get my head around setting up Server 2003 + Active Directory on Oracle VirtualBox. I have completed so far:

- Installed Server 2003
- Installed SP2
- Installed Active Directory

As of now, I can access the internet via the NAT connection assigned to the VM, but I'm unable to ping the server from the Host OS (`ping server-01` | `ping pitts.internal`).

I'm aware that I will need to create some custom IP Settings, but I'm not sure exactly how to go about this.

Note: the reason I have to set up this server is because of development of an application on the host OS for my company, As I'm a Desktop / Web developer I'm struggling with some of the settings for the server.

Comment: What has this to do with VMWare? it's unclear, also VMWare is a company not a product, what of their products are you discussing?

Comment: I don't think it is VMWare as the poster states 'Oracle VM'. I think this post is aimed at VirtualBox, in which case the manual is here: http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/UserManual.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you mean Oracle VirtualBox VM, have a read of this section of the manual: http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html

Essentially by using NAT, your VM's will need to be on the subnet chosen by your VirtualBox installation. VirtualBox has a DHCP server which will allocate addresses automatically which is why you can access the internet from your VMs.

AD/DNS will need to be on a static address on this subnet, not DHCP. I would start by pinging the IP address and not the name too.

Answer (score 0):

Do You ping by iP address or name of the guest os? If by name, why host os have to know this name? Do You set up DNS records for that?  Your example uses name.